# App Inventor or Android studio? Which one is better?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, app-inventor

I would like to know how different between android studio and app inventor and I want to know what program that you use for android application development
and I would like to know the advantage of android studio and App Inventor too

Thanks for every answer.

Comment: stable & better = android studio..because google product.

Answer (score 5):

**Why to use Android Studio?**
 I use and recommend using Android Studio. It is fast and easy to use. Above all, it is the official IDE for Android. Though, in Android Studio, you have to write your own code. 
 **Why to use App Inventor?**
 App Inventor uses a graphic interface and coding in App Inventor isn't necessary. It has a drag-and-drop interface. 
 **Conclusion** 
 If you're a beginner in Android programming, use App Inventor, but if you're a advanced programmer, use Android Studio. Studio provides more functions than App Inventor.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely Android Studio. App Inventor is to make it easier for any non-programmer or newcomer to easily understand the primary concepts on Android app development in an intuitive and cost-effective manner. If you have no previous experience in programming then go with App Inventor but your options are much limited than using a full-fledged IDE. If you want to built complex apps (not limited by the options that App Inventor provides to you) then learn to program in Android Studio (Java is required).

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio is the official IDE for Android application development, based on IntelliJ IDEA. Android Studio is approved by Google, so use it.

http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I use Android Studio. I think everyone should use it because it is official application from Android developers. It is also available for most platforms.